# Tests in Vapor thrown Fatal Error before tests are run

Tags: swift, testing, vapor

I've been running tests on a Vapor project, which have been running happily. With no apparent changes, and none to the setup and breakdown routines, now they refuse to start, with the error

```
Vapor/Application.swift:154: Fatal error: Application.shutdown() was not called before Application deinitialized.
2021-08-28 15:15:45.136991+0700 xctest[9353:93515] Vapor/Application.swift:154: Fatal error: Application.shutdown() was not called before Application deinitialized.
```

I've got auto migrate turned on, and I've tried blowing away the docker psql instance, and recreating it. The app runs fine on localhost, and on the remote server: I just can't get tests to start and run.

There's only one test document, and it starts with this:

```
@testable import App
import XCTVapor
import Fluent

final class NewTests: XCTestCase {
    static var app : Application!
    static var stdPass = "12345"
    
    var app = NewTests.app
    var stdPass = stdPass
    
//    SETUP AND TEARDOWN =================================================
    override func setUp() { NewTests.app = try! Application.testable(); app = NewTests.app }
    
    override func tearDown() { NewTests.app.shutdown() }


    func testBasicTournamentCreate() throws {

      …
    }
```

There are two tests: one is basic, and the other is very long, since we have to replicate the conditions in a complex situation, with random input from a number of users interacting with the app. That doesn't seem to be the issue, since if I run only the simple, short test, I get the same result.

The targets in `package.swift` look like this:

```
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: [.target(name: "App")]), // comment what follows
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
```

I remember having a similar problem, but some combination of a recreation of the database, cleaning the build folder and eventually a restart fixed it. I've tried all that, and no dice...

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the test app can't connect to a database. Do double check your database configuration and make sure it matches whatever test database you're trying to connect to.

The easiest way to find out what's going on is to wrap any try's in a do/catch and see what the error is. What's happening is something is throwing an error, causing the test case to exit and deinitialise the `Application` instance before your call to `shutdown` has been triggered

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was a typo in a migration, but in a string literal field name (so the compiler didn't catch it), and in the revert clause, so it happened only after the db had been initialized. This meant that I eliminated the migration, because after the test had run, I could see the complete schema.... ah well.

Comment: Hi, can you post the detail? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Thanks.